# dart: cannot add new list to a 2D list

Tags: arrays, list, dart, data-structures

I have a 2D list, and I'd love to append new 1D lists to it.
But the following code fails when I append.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  List<List<double>> ll;
  var rng = Random();
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var l = List<double>.generate(100, (_)=> -96.0 + rng.nextDouble()*96.0);
    ll.add(l);  // Script error in Dart online sandbox.
  }
  var length = ll.length;
  print("bye: $length");
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list `ll` doesn't reference a list (yet), so there isn't anything to add `l` to.

You need to initialise `ll` such as

```
List<List<double>> ll = [];
```

or

```
List<List<double>> ll = new List();
```